# In Groovy, why does the behaviour of '==' change for interfaces extending Comparable?

Tags: groovy, equality

I'm trying to develop a project in Groovy and I've found some of my tests failing in an odd way: I have an interface `Version extends Comparable<Version>` with two concrete subclasses. Both override `equals(Object)` and `compareTo(Version)` - however, if I try to compare two instances of `Version` that are of different concrete types using `==`, the equality check fails even though explicit `equals` and `compareTo` checks pass.

If I remove the `extends Comparable<Version>` part of `Version`, I get the expected behaviour - `==` gives the same result as `equals` would.

I've read elsewhere that Groovy delegates `==` to `equals()` unless the class implements `Comparable`, in which case it delegates to `compareTo`. However, I'm finding cases where both declare two instances of `Version` to be equal and yet the `==` checks fail.

I've created an SSCCE that demonstrates this behaviour [here](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5705097937944576).

The full code is also provided below:

```
// Interface extending Comparable
interface Super extends Comparable<Super> {
    int getValue()
}

class SubA implements Super {
    int getValue() { 1 }
    int compareTo(Super that) { this.value <=> that.value }
    boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == null) return false
        if (!(o instanceof Super)) return false
        this.value == o.value
    }
}

class SubB implements Super {
    int getValue() { 1 }
    int compareTo(Super that) { this.value <=> that.value }
    boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == null) return false
        if (!(o instanceof Super)) return false
        this.value == o.value
    }
}

// Interface not extending Comparable
interface AnotherSuper {
    int getValue()
}

class AnotherSubA implements AnotherSuper {
    int getValue() { 1 }
    boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == null) return false
        if (!(o instanceof AnotherSuper)) return false
        this.value == o.value
    }
}

class AnotherSubB implements AnotherSuper {
    int getValue() { 1 }
    boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == null) return false
        if (!(o instanceof AnotherSuper)) return false
        this.value == o.value
    }
}


// Check with comparable versions
def a = new SubA()
def b = new SubB()

println "Comparable versions equality check: ${a == b}"
println "Explicit comparable equals check: ${a.equals(b)}"
println "Explicit comparable compareTo check: ${a.compareTo(b)}"

// Check with non-comparable versions
def anotherA = new AnotherSubA()
def anotherB = new AnotherSubB()

println "Non-comparable versions equality check: ${anotherA == anotherB}"
println "Explicit non-comparable equals check: ${anotherA.equals(anotherB)}"
```

What I'm getting back is:

```
Comparable versions equality check: false
Explicit comparable equals check: true
Explicit comparable compareTo check: 0
Non-comparable versions equality check: true
Explicit non-comparable equals check: true
```

**EDIT**
I think I understand why this happens now, thanks to the [JIRA discussion](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-3364) that Poundex linked to below.

From Groovy's [DefaultTypeTransformation class](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/typehandling/DefaultTypeTransformation.java#L557), which is used to handle equality/comparison checks, I assume that the `compareEqual` method is first called when a statement of the form `x == y` is being evaluated:

```
public static boolean compareEqual(Object left, Object right) {
    if (left == right) return true;
    if (left == null || right == null) return false;
    if (left instanceof Comparable) {
        return compareToWithEqualityCheck(left, right, true) == 0;
    }
    // handle arrays on both sides as special case for efficiency
    Class leftClass = left.getClass();
    Class rightClass = right.getClass();
    if (leftClass.isArray() && rightClass.isArray()) {
        return compareArrayEqual(left, right);
    }
    if (leftClass.isArray() && leftClass.getComponentType().isPrimitive()) {
        left = primitiveArrayToList(left);
    }
    if (rightClass.isArray() && rightClass.getComponentType().isPrimitive()) {
        right = primitiveArrayToList(right);
    }
    if (left instanceof Object[] && right instanceof List) {
        return DefaultGroovyMethods.equals((Object[]) left, (List) right);
    }
    if (left instanceof List && right instanceof Object[]) {
        return DefaultGroovyMethods.equals((List) left, (Object[]) right);
    }
    if (left instanceof List && right instanceof List) {
        return DefaultGroovyMethods.equals((List) left, (List) right);
    }
    if (left instanceof Map.Entry && right instanceof Map.Entry) {
        Object k1 = ((Map.Entry)left).getKey();
        Object k2 = ((Map.Entry)right).getKey();
        if (k1 == k2 || (k1 != null && k1.equals(k2))) {
            Object v1 = ((Map.Entry)left).getValue();
            Object v2 = ((Map.Entry)right).getValue();
            if (v1 == v2 || (v1 != null && DefaultTypeTransformation.compareEqual(v1, v2)))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    return ((Boolean) InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(left, "equals", right)).booleanValue();
}
```

Notice that if the LHS of the expression is an instance of `Comparable`, as it is in the example I provide, the comparison is delegated to `compareToWithEqualityCheck`:

```
private static int compareToWithEqualityCheck(Object left, Object right, boolean equalityCheckOnly) {
    if (left == right) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (left == null) {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (right == null) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (left instanceof Comparable) {
        if (left instanceof Number) {
            if (right instanceof Character || right instanceof Number) {
                return DefaultGroovyMethods.compareTo((Number) left, castToNumber(right));
            }
            if (isValidCharacterString(right)) {
                return DefaultGroovyMethods.compareTo((Number) left, ShortTypeHandling.castToChar(right));
            }
        }
        else if (left instanceof Character) {
            if (isValidCharacterString(right)) {
                return DefaultGroovyMethods.compareTo((Character)left, ShortTypeHandling.castToChar(right));
            }
            if (right instanceof Number) {
                return DefaultGroovyMethods.compareTo((Character)left,(Number)right);
            }
        }
        else if (right instanceof Number) {
            if (isValidCharacterString(left)) {
                return DefaultGroovyMethods.compareTo(ShortTypeHandling.castToChar(left),(Number) right);
            }
        }
        else if (left instanceof String && right instanceof Character) {
            return ((String) left).compareTo(right.toString());
        }
        else if (left instanceof String && right instanceof GString) {
            return ((String) left).compareTo(right.toString());
        }
        if (!equalityCheckOnly || left.getClass().isAssignableFrom(right.getClass())
                || (right.getClass() != Object.class && right.getClass().isAssignableFrom(left.getClass())) //GROOVY-4046
                || (left instanceof GString && right instanceof String)) {
            Comparable comparable = (Comparable) left;
            return comparable.compareTo(right);
        }
    }

    if (equalityCheckOnly) {
        return -1; // anything other than 0
    }
    throw new GroovyRuntimeException(
            MessageFormat.format("Cannot compare {0} with value ''{1}'' and {2} with value ''{3}''",
                    left.getClass().getName(),
                    left,
                    right.getClass().getName(),
                    right));
}
```

Down near the bottom, the method has a block that delegates the comparison to the `compareTo` method, *but only if certain conditions are satisfied*. In the example I provide, none of these conditions are satisfied, including the `isAssignableFrom` check, since the example classes I provide (and the code in my project that's giving me the problem) are *siblings*, and therefore not assignable to one another.

I suppose I understand why the checks are failing now, but I'm still puzzled over the following things:

1. How do I get around this?
2. What's the rationale behind this? Is this a bug or a design feature? Is there any reason why two subclasses of a common super class should not be comparable with one another?

Comment: Looks like you might have this https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-3364 (I tried it locally with 2.4.0 and saw the same results as you)

Comment: @Poundex Thanks for the link. I saw one of the comments mention that '<=>' and '==' go through [here](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/typehandling/DefaultTypeTransformation.java) - of particular interest are `compareToWithEqualityCheck` and `compareEqual`. I'm still not sure exactly what's happening, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to why Comparable is used for == if existing is easy. It is because of BigDecimal. If you make a BigDecimal out of "1.0" and "1.00" (use Strings not doubles!) you get two BigDecimal that are not equal according to equals, because they don't have the same scale. Value-wise they are equal though, which is why compareTo will see them as equal.

Then of course there is also [GROOVY-4046](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-4046), which shows a case in which just directly calling compareTo will lead to a ClassCastException. Since this exception is unexpected here we decided to add an check for assignability.

To get around this you can use `<=>` instead which you already found. Yes, they still go through `DefaultTypeTransformation` so you can compare for example an int and an long. If you don't want that either, then directly calling compareTo is the way to go. If I misunderstood you and you want to actually have equals, well, then you should call equals of course instead.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.

Using compareTo (via the spaceship operator) does work, but it's not very convenient: I would need to do something like `(v1 <=> v2) == 0` to test for equality.

What I would like is to be able to use '==' to check for equality. `v1.equals(v2)` would work, but I would prefer to use `==` if possible. This is probably a dumb question as I'm still relatively new to Groovy but is there not a way I can override the '==' operator for these particular classes to make them immediately delegate to `equals` or `compareTo` as I define them in the classes?

Comment: In this case I'm afraid the only way would be to use an AST transform and change the BinaryExpression into a MethodCallExpression. Not sure you want to go that far. But you made me thinking if calling compareTo is actually needed... but even then, this would be for a future  Groovy version

Comment: If that's the only way then I'll stick with `equals` for now and mark your answer as accepted. I'm not sure whether or not eliminating the call to `compareTo` is necessary, but I will say that I believe '==' checks would pass in my case if the requirement that `left.getClass().isAssignableFrom(right.getClass())` is relaxed to just checking the two classes derive from some common `Comparable`-extending interface or implementing superclass. I don't know if that will create other problems, but I feel `ConcreteVersionA` and `ConcreteVersionB` should be mutually comparable (with '==').