# Is there a way to make the @Builder annotation work for immutable classes?

Tags: groovy, immutability, builder

I'm trying to develop a project in Groovy and I've been looking through my code and trying to find areas which I could replace with something more idiomatically Groovy until I find a solution for [another issue I've been having](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28355773/in-groovy-why-does-the-behaviour-of-change-for-interfaces-extending-compar).

I've started taking a more in-depth look into the use of AST transformation annotations - they've helped significantly cut down on the amount of code I have to write in some places. However, I'm having an issue using the `groovy.transform.builder.Builder` annotation with one of my immutable value classes. The source for this annotation is hosted [here](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/groovy/transform/builder/Builder.java).

The issue is that the annotation seems to make the builder set the values of the buildee directly rather than storing a copy of the values and passing them to the buildee's constructor. This results in a `ReadOnlyPropertyException` when you try to use it with immutable classes.

There are four possible Builder strategies you can select with this annotation, and of them I've tried `DefaultStrategy`, `ExternalStrategy` and `InitializerStrategy`. However, all of these have caused problems.

`ExternalStrategy` looks like the most promising of the four, and you can find an SSCCE based on it detailing the problem [here](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5641206004449280).

The source code from the example is also included below:

```
import groovy.transform.Immutable
import groovy.transform.builder.Builder as GBuilder
import groovy.transform.builder.ExternalStrategy

/*
* Uncommenting the below causes a failure:
* 'groovy.lang.ReadOnlyPropertyException: Cannot set readonly property: value for class: Value'
*/
//@Immutable
class Value {

    @GBuilder(forClass = Value, prefix = 'set', builderStrategy = ExternalStrategy)
    static class Builder { }

    int value
    String toString() { "Value($value)" }
}

def builder = new Value.Builder()
println builder.setValue(1).build()
```

There also seems to be a relevant JIRA discussion on the matter [here](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-6484).

**Edit**
I've tried using CFrick's answer below, using `InitializerStrategy` rather than `ExternalStrategy`.

Everything now compiles, but I get the following errors at run-time when I try to execute my tests:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class com.github.tagc.semver.version.BaseVersion from class com.github.tagc.semver.version.BaseVersion$com.github.tagc.semver.version.BaseVersionInitializer
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaringClass(Class.java:1227)
    at java.beans.MethodRef.set(MethodRef.java:46)
    at java.beans.MethodDescriptor.setMethod(MethodDescriptor.java:117)
    at java.beans.MethodDescriptor.<init>(MethodDescriptor.java:72)
    at java.beans.MethodDescriptor.<init>(MethodDescriptor.java:56)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getTargetMethodInfo(Introspector.java:1163)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:426)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:173)
    at com.github.tagc.semver.version.VersionFactory.createBaseVersion(VersionFactory.groovy:34)
    at com.github.tagc.semver.test.util.TestSetup.<clinit>(TestSetup.groovy:77)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:344)
    at com.github.tagc.semver.version.SnapshotDecoratorSpec.#decoratedVersion should be considered equal to patch-bumped #releaseVersion snapshot(SnapshotDecoratorSpec.groovy:24)
```

Followed thereafter by a series of exceptions like the following:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.github.tagc.semver.test.util.TestSetup
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:344)
    at com.github.tagc.semver.version.SnapshotDecoratorSpec.#decoratedVersion should be considered equal to minor-bumped #releaseVersion snapshot(SnapshotDecoratorSpec.groovy:36)
```

What I have right now is a `BaseVersion` class like the following:

```
/**
 * A concrete, base implementation of {@link com.github.tagc.semver.version.Version Version}.
 *
 * @author davidfallah
 * @since v0.1.0
 */
@Immutable
@Builder(prefix = 'set', builderStrategy = InitializerStrategy)
@PackageScope
final class BaseVersion implements Version {
    // ...

    /**
     * The major category of this version.
     */
    int major = 0

    /**
     * The minor category of this version.
     */
    int minor = 0

    /**
     * The patch category of this version.
     */
    int patch = 0

    /**
     * Whether this version is a release or snapshot version.
     */
    boolean release = false

    // ...
}
```

A factory to produce instances of these:

```
/**
 * A factory for producing base and decorated {@code Version} objects.
 *
 * @author davidfallah
 * @since v0.5.0
 */
class VersionFactory {

    // ...

    /**
     * Returns an instance of {@link com.github.tagc.semver.version.BaseVersion BaseVersion} constructed
     * with the given parameters.
     *
     * @param major the major category value of the version instance
     * @param minor the minor category value of the version instance
     * @param patch the patch category value of the version instance
     * @param release the release setting of the version instance
     * @return an instance of {@code BaseVersion}
     */
    static BaseVersion createBaseVersion(int major, int minor, int patch, boolean release) {
        return new BaseVersion(major, minor, patch, release)
    }

    /**
     * Returns an instance of {@link com.github.tagc.semver.version.BaseVersion BaseVersion} constructed
     * with the given parameters.
     *
     * @param m a map of parameter names and their corresponding values corresponding to the
     *        construction parameters of {@code BaseVersion}.
     *
     * @return an instance of {@code BaseVersion}
     */
    static BaseVersion createBaseVersion(Map m) {
        return new BaseVersion(m)
    }

    /**
     * Returns an instance of {@link com.github.tagc.semver.version.BaseVersion BaseVersion} constructed
     * with the given parameters.
     *
     * @param l a list of parameter values corresponding to the construction parameters of {@code BaseVersion}.
     *
     * @return an instance of {@code BaseVersion}
     */
    static BaseVersion createBaseVersion(List l) {
        return new BaseVersion(l)
    }

    /**
     * Returns a builder for {@link com.github.tagc.semver.version.BaseVersion BaseVersion} to specify
     * the construction parameters for the {@code BaseVersion} incrementally.
     *
     * @return an instance of {@code BaseVersion.Builder}
     */
    static Object createBaseVersionBuilder() {
        return BaseVersion.builder()
    }

    // ...
}
```

A test specification class for `Version` objects:

```
/**
 * Test specification for {@link com.github.tagc.semver.version.Version Version}.
 *
 * @author davidfallah
 * @since 0.1.0
 */
@Unroll
class VersionSpec extends Specification {

    static exampleVersions = [
        VersionFactory.createBaseVersion(major:1, minor:2, patch:3),
        VersionFactory.createBaseVersion(major:0, minor:0, patch:0),
        VersionFactory.createBaseVersion(major:5, minor:4, patch:3),
        VersionFactory.createBaseVersion(major:1, minor:16, patch:2),
        VersionFactory.createBaseVersion(major:4, minor:5, patch:8),
        ]

    // ...
}
```

And other classes that try to create instances of `BaseVersion` that are failing, such as `TestSetup`.

Comment: `@Immutable` is final by default.  could you please provide a minimal failing version of the code?  it's hard to follow as it is right now.  also why `@PackageScope`?

Comment: @cfrick I'll try to put something together and update you when I'm done. `@PackageScope` because it's best to restrict scope as much as possible. I want the `Version` interface to be public but the concrete implementations to be package-private so that clients are forced to go through `VersionFactory` to construct them (static factory methods are often better than constructors [Effective Java Item 1]). I haven't played enough with this yet to be sure this is the best approach, but I'll try something different if it doesn't work out.

Comment: @cfrick While making an SSCCE I discovered I was misusing the Initializer approach. I've corrected my mistake and now it seems to be working fine, so I'm marking your answer as accepted. However, I don't really like the initializer approach (especially since it requires getting rid of `@PackageScope`), so I'm just going to stick with the old-fashioned actually-in-the-source-code approach I had before. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code there fails, because chosen strategy there basically does:

```
 def v = new Value().with{ setValue(1); return it }
```

and this can not be done on `@Immutable` objects.

According to the [docs](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/#xform-Builder), there is only `InitializerStrategy`, that can explicitly cope with `@Immutable`.

> You can use the InitializerStrategy in conjunction with @Canonical and @Immutable. If your @Builder annotation doesn’t have explicit includes or excludes annotation attributes but your @Canonical annotation does, the ones from @Canonical will be re-used for @Builder.

E.g.

```
import groovy.transform.*
import groovy.transform.builder.*

@Immutable
@ToString
@Builder(prefix='set', builderStrategy=InitializerStrategy)
class Value {
    int value
}

def builder = Value.createInitializer().setValue(1)
assert new Value(builder).toString()=='Value(1)'
```

Depending on what you are up to, this is rahter ugly syntax and you might be better off just using the Map-based c'tors.  Even without e.g. `@TypeChecked` a `new Value(vlaue: 666)` will generate an error and leaving params (for a class with multiple properties) will leave them `null`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. "Depending on what you are up to, this is rahter ugly syntax and you might be better off just using the Map-based c'tors." This is a possibility, but as I saw mentioned in a JIRA discussion somewhere, using a builder promotes interoperability with Java. Your approach makes everything compilable, so it seems to be along the right lines and for that reason I've upvoted it. However, I now get `IllegalAccessError`s, so I'm afraid I can't accept this answer right now since others may experience this issue as well with this approach. I've updated the original post.