# Does Groovy Builder transformation really work?

Tags: groovy, builder

```
plugins {
    id 'groovy'
    id 'java'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.15'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    testImplementation ('org.spockframework:spock-core:1.1-groovy-2.4') {
        exclude group: 'org.codehaus.groovy'
    }
}
```

I tried to use the [Builder](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/gapi/groovy/transform/builder/Builder.html) transform in the following code:

```
package pattern

import groovy.transform.builder.Builder
import groovy.transform.builder.DefaultStrategy

@Builder
class HttpRequestBuilderAnnotation {

    //Mandatory
    private final String url
    private final String httpMethod
    private final String requestContentType
    private final String acceptContentType

    //Optional
    private final String requestBody
    private final List<Integer> validResponseCodes

    String getUrl() {
        return url
    }

    String getHttpMethod() {
        return httpMethod
    }

    String getRequestContentType() {
        return requestContentType
    }

    String getAcceptContentType() {
        return acceptContentType
    }

    String getRequestBody() {
        return requestBody
    }

    List<Integer> getValidResponseCodes() {
        return validResponseCodes
    }
}
```

The test case:

```
package pattern

import spock.lang.Specification

class HttpRequestBuilderAnnotationSpec extends Specification {

    private String url = 'https://dsd.com'

    void "Instantiate HttpRequest"() {

        when:
        HttpRequestBuilderAnnotation httpRequestBuilderAnnotation = HttpRequestBuilderAnnotation.builder()
                                                                    .url(url).build()

        then:
        assert httpRequestBuilderAnnotation
        assert httpRequestBuilderAnnotation.getUrl() == url
    }
}
```

The error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static pattern.HttpRequestBuilderAnnotation.url() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [https://dsd.com]
Possible solutions: use([Ljava.lang.Object;), grep(), dump(), any(), getUrl(), use(java.lang.Class, groovy.lang.Closure)

    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at pattern.HttpRequestBuilderAnnotationSpec.Instantiate HttpRequest(HttpRequestBuilderAnnotationSpec.groovy:12)
```

----------Note:
If the 'private' modifier is removed, the code works but I believe as per the Groovy specification, the private modifiers should work as-is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to make the @Builder annotation work for immutable classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28385275/is-there-a-way-to-make-the-builder-annotation-work-for-immutable-classes)

Comment: Not really. I am merely trying to use the Builder transform for a plain Fluent API style method.

Comment: But you are using the default strategy with immutable (final) fields.